# pymongo Get an Image Back Out of GridFS

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I am playing around with MongoDB and the pymongo API. I can put an image file in to GridFS - seems straight forward:

```
>>> f = open('myimage.jpg', 'r')
>>> fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
>>> fid = fs.put(f)
>>> fid
ObjectId('4efde2c27c7778121800000a')
```

Looks like it has worked. I can also query GridFS using the _id returned:

```
>>> fs.exists(fid)
True
```

But I dont seem to be able to get the WHOLE file back out - it looks like I am getting a chunK?

```
>>> fs.get(fid).read()
'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00Z\x00Z\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00
\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01
\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x02\x02\x01\x01
\x02\x01\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02
\x02\x02\x02\x02\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x02\x0
1\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x0
2\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x0
2\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x03\x8d\x0
2X\x03\x01"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\
x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\
t\n\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x02\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x04\x00\
x00\x01}\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05\x12!1A\x06\x13Qa\x07"q\x142\x81\x91\xa1\x08
#B\xb1\xc1\x15R\xd1\xf0$3br\x82\t\n\x16\x17\x18\x19'
>>> f.tell()
352256L
```

I did a tell() on the original file and you can see that it is much larger than what I get out of GridFS. If I do a tell() on the file that I get back from GridFS it is in the region of 274. (I understand that tell() just tells you the pointer location in the file, but it gives an indication of how big it is after reading.)

I am obviously missing something here! How can I get the file back out of GridFS in its entirety?

I am running v2.0.2 of mongodb and v2.1 of pymongo on v2.7 of python.

Comment: You can use `GridOut.length` to see how many bytes are actually stored which could give you an indication as to whether you are not getting all of the bytes out or if the file wasn't fully stored.

Comment: @cpburnz - Thanks - Yes, I tried that too, returns a value of 274 (same as using tell()), which leads me to think this is a chunk that I am getting back.

Comment: What version of pymongo are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have included that in the question - I am using v2.1 of pymongo and running v2.0.2 of mongod.

Comment: The code you have above should work. One thing to note is that if you've already `read()` or `seek()`-ed on the file, then GridFS will only begin writing into the database from the current file "cursor" position. If you want to be careful (and you're working with seekable files), you can add `f.seek(0, 0)` before `fs.put(...)` to explicitly seek back to the beginning.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that and it did not help. I tried to "put" the file using the mongofiles app - worked. I could then use pymongo to see that the file exists (worked) and I could use GridFS.get_last_version(filename) to get the GridOut instance. Using that I can see that the file size is 355846, which is what I expected to see. Using mongofiles -get allowed me to get the file back out of GridFS and it was identical to the original. So I must be doing something wrong reading the file to GridFS using pymongo and file object. I am not a seasoned python developer, can you see anything obvious? Thx

Comment: a few things to check - 1) if you're on windows, open the file with 'rb' mode, not just 'r'. 2) make sure the file you're opening has been written to completely before inserting into mongo. 3) make sure f is positioned at the beginning of the file prior to calling put()

Answer (score 2):

Get data to outputdata

```
outputdata =fs.get(stored).read()
```

Define file path and open write mode

```
outfilename = "path to output file"
output= open(outfilename,"w")
```

Write data and close file

```
output.write(outputdata)
output.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check wether GridFS actually holds the entire file, i.e. you've not written a part of the file through the mongo console. This should list your image along with others along with the length of the each file. So you can verify wether GridFS actually holds you entire file or not.

```
db.fs.files.find().pretty()
```

If it does not hold your file fully, then propably you did something messy while writing it to the GridFS (like what [@dcrosta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681726/pymongo-get-an-image-back-out-of-gridfs#comment10796587_8681726) said)

***Note: replace your collection name in the above command with "fs"**. Like:

```
db.<my_collection_name>.files.find().pretty()
```

If you have a lot of files then try:

```
db.<my_collection_name>.files.findOne({'_id' : ObjectId("your object id as a hex string")})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing 'r' to 'rb' as folowing: `>>> f = open('myimage.jpg', 'rb')`

Depending on your platform (win/linux/mac) this might cause problems